# Explicit expression of a counter

Tags: loops

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
cont = 0
for g = 1,...,m
        for h = g,...,m
                cont = cont + 1
        end for
end for
```

I'm searching for the explicit map that returns `cont` in function of `g` and `h`. I've tried with

`cont = m*(g - 1) + [h - (g - 1)]`

but this formula works only in the case `m = 2`.

---

**observation**
for the following cycle

```
cont = 0
for g = 1,...,m
        for h = 1,...,m
                cont = cont + 1
        end for
end for
```

the value of `cont` in function of `g` and `h` is given by
`cont = m*(g - 1) + h`

Comment: Try plotting the possible combinations of `g` and `h` in a coordinate system, and marking those where the counter is incremented. You'll find that the relevant cases form one half of a rectangle. That should tell you what the total number of increments is.

Comment: Hint: `g` and `h` are defined within that code, `m` is the only input

Comment: Just to be sure: I don't want count how many increment there are in the two cycles (which are  `m*(m+1)/2`) but I want to find the map that returns the value of `cont` in given `g` and `h`. For example, if `m=3`, what is the value of `cont` at the iteration with`g=2` and `h=3`?

Comment: So you want a container of `(g, h, count)` tuples? Or a function that - unlike the one you sketched - maps `(m, g, h) -> count`?

Comment: I'm searching for a mathematical function that given `m`, `g`, `h` compute the value of `count`. I'm sorry for my imprecision, I hope to have clarified my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to reflect the question "Actually what I'm searching is an answer to the following question: given `m`, if suddenly I interrupt the cycle in a point where `g` and `h` has some specific value, e.g. `g=2` and `h=3`, what is the value assumed by `cont`?" [given in a comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/421071/explicit-expression-of-a-counter/421087#comment927195_421087).

If we stop the execution at the point where `g = g'` and `h = h'`, we can represent that using the following algorithm:

```
cont = 0
for g = 1,...,g' - 1
     for h = g,...,m
          cont = cont + 1
     end for
end for
for h = g',..., h'
    cont = cont + 1
end for
```

(I'm assuming we stop execution *after* `cont = cont + 1` is executed one last time. If that's not desired, you can simply subtract 1 from the final answer.)

We can do the same thing again:

```
cont = 0
for g = 1,...,g' - 1
     cont = cont + m - g + 1
end for
cont = cont + h' - g' + 1
```

Factor out the constants for simplicity:

```
cont = (g' - 1) * (m + 1) + h' - g' + 1
for g = 1,...,g' - 1
     cont = cont - g
end for
```

And we can use the triangle number trick again now:

```
cont = (g' - 1) * (m + 1) + h' - g' + 1 - (g' - 1) * g' / 2
```

Rearranging everything to get the final closed-form formula:

```
cont = (g' - 1) * (m - g' / 2) + h'
```

---

### The original answer

As @Caleth mentioned, `m` is the only free variable in your code.

First:

```
for a = 1,...,b
        cont = cont + 1
end for
```

is equivalent to

```
cont = cont + b
```

And by extension:

```
for h = g,...,m
        cont = cont + 1
end for
```

is equivalent to

```
cont = cont + m - g + 1
```

We can now simplify the code to:

```
cont = 0
for g = 1,...,m
         cont = cont + m - g + 1
end for
```

Factoring out the parts that don't depend on `g`:

```
cont = m * (m + 1)
for g = 1,...,m
         cont = cont - g
end for
```

we can change that to:

```
cont = m * (m + 1)
subtract = 0
for g = 1,...,m
         subtract = subtract + g
end for
cont = cont - subtract
```

You can now see that the final values of `subtract` for consecutive values of `m` for the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). Wikipedia says `n * (n + 1) / 2` as a closed-form formula for the `n`th triangle number. Plugging that in gives:

we can change that to:

```
cont = m * (m + 1)
subtract = m * (m + 1) / 2
cont = cont - subtract
```

which means we end up with:

```
cont = m * (m + 1) / 2
```

Comment: Thank you Jasmijn for your answer, but I'm not searching for the final value of the counter. I know that I have formulated the problem in a confusing way. Actually what I'm searching is an answer to the following question: given `m` , if suddenly I interrupt the cycle in a point where `g` and `h` has some specific value, e.g. `g=2` and `h=3`, what is the value assumed by `cont`?
I view `cont` as a mathematical function of `g` and `h`, where `m` plays the role of an external parameter.

Comment: Ah, alright. I'll amend my answer then.

Comment: Your solution works like a charm, thank you Jamsijn for your help.